# Methods to align/reduce distance between two or more 3D graph-spaces?

Tags: r, spatial, networks

I'm trying to align multiple graphs of spatial data, similar to image registration, but on a 3D graphspace of a select feature. I have a bunch of point data with x,y,z coordinates that together, constructs a cone-like structure for each sample. Across 30 samples, however, some are shifted forward or backward, the angle is rotated, etc. I'd like to merge them all to have a common coordinate system in place. I'm imagining building a knn network for each sample to capture the transition in angle through space, then presumably there's a cost function that can shift one graphspace to reach a minimal difference to the other (i.e align the two cones).

Seems like a simple task, but I've tried searching this issue all morning without much avail. Any methods you could direct me to to accomplish this would be appreciated! If it helps, I'm working in R.